# Prevent TMUX from starting in intellij terminal

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, zsh, tmux

So I have the following snippet:

```
if [[ ps -p$PPID | grep 'java' == '' ]]; then
    ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true;
fi
```

which returns the following error:

```
/home/otis/.zshrc:8: parse error: condition expected: ps
```

The idea is that if `ps -p$PPID | grep 'java'` returns nothing then set `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true`.

The reason I want to do this is I want to automagically start tmux in my gnome-terminal but not in my intellij terminal if I run this command in gnome it returns nothing and if I run from intellij it returns `java`.

So the logic is solid basically if there is nothing returned always start tmux, but I am not that good at shell so any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this is an old thread and the TERMINAL_EMULATOR variable may not have been the same at the time of the original post but I solved this on OSX with the following:

```
if [ "$TERMINAL_EMULATOR" != "JetBrains-JediTerm"]
then 
   ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get an error message is due to the conditional expression (`[[ … ]]`) expecting a condition after `ps`, which it takes for a string not a command. You have to wrap the command in `$(…)` to use its output inside the conditional expression. Alternatively you could just use the exit code of `grep` to determine whether "java" has been found, which removes the need for a conditional expression.

```
if ! ps -p $PPID | grep -q java; then
    ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true;
fi
```

Note that the the return values of the check are reversed to what you originally intended. Hence the `!` to return `true` if the exit code would be `false` and vise versa. `-q` just suppresses the output of `grep`.

Comment: This worked really well I ended up using `if ! ps -p $PPID | grep -q java; then` so I added the `!` (not) modifier this way I was able to avoid the `else` statement.

Comment: @OtisWright You are of course correct, `!` makes for a clearer statement. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, under Settings > Tools > Terminal, set Environment variables to `INSIDE_EMACS=true`.